# Kanban view in OpenERP

Tags: odoo, kanban

How do I create a kanban view in OpenERP?

The [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/index.html#book-develop-link) doesn't seem to have any information on the new kanban view, and I didn't see anything useful in the [OpenERP forum](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3aopenerp.com%20inurl%3aforum%20kanban).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is sample code showing how to develop a kanban view in OpenERP.

For the kanban view you have to prepare 2 files: (1)xml file and (2) css file. The CSS file is used for the formating of the kanban view.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="resource_kanban_view">
    <field name="name">any name of ur  model</field>
    <field name="model">object.name</field>
    <field name="type">kanban</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban>
            <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div class="oe_resource_vignette">
                        <div class="oe_resource_image">
                            <a type="edit"><img t-att-src="kanban_image('object.name', 'photo', record.id.value)" class="oe_resource_picture"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oe_resource_details">
                            <ul>
<!--Here you have to write the object's field name which you want to display in kanban view -->
                               <li><field name="name"/></li>
                               <li><field name="author"/></li>
                               <li><field name="description"/></li>
                               <li><field name="available_copy"/> </li>                                   
                             </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 4):

Their is Doc on this, KANBAN view is created based on QWEB technology, developed by OF itself, you can see the the whole lib [QWEB lib](https://github.com/antonylesuisse/qweb) and under Doc Section you can see how you can define the qWeb [QWEB Template](https://github.com/antonylesuisse/qweb/blob/master/doc/template.html), Now if you understand it then all you just need to do is out your web template under  tag in view declaration, where other systex is same as generic view declaration :

```
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_external_id">
        <field name="name">View Name</field>
        <field name="model">openerp.modelfield>
        <field name="type">kanban</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
             <kanban>
                <field name="color"/>
                <!--list of field to be loaded -->
                <field name="list_price"/>
                <templates>
                     <!--Your Qweb based template goes here, each record will be wrapped in template so you can arrange field veyr easily in box -->
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Hope this will help you.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any documentation for it yet, so the best you can do is look for examples in the addons project. Search all the XML files for `<kanban>`. Here's an example from the [stock module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/6714/stock/product_view.xml#L129):

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product.product_kanban_view">
        <field name="name">Product Kanban</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="type">kanban</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban>
                <field name="color"/>
                <field name="type"/>
                <field name="product_image"/>
                <field name="list_price"/>
                <templates>
                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div class="oe_product_vignette">
                            <div class="oe_product_img">
                            <a type="edit"><img t-att-src="kanban_image('product.product', 'product_image', record.id.value)" class="oe_product_photo"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="oe_product_desc">
                                <h4><a type="edit"><field name="name"></field></a></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li t-if="record.type.raw_value != 'service'">Stock on hand: <field name="qty_available"/> <field name="uom_id"/></li>
                                    <li t-if="record.type.raw_value != 'service'">Stock available: <field name="virtual_available"/> <field name="uom_id"/></li>
                                    <li>Price: <field name="lst_price"></field></li>
                                    <li>Cost: <field name="standard_price"></field></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            $('.oe_product_photo').load(function() { if($(this).width() > $(this).height()) { $(this).addClass('oe_product_photo_wide') } });
                        </script>
                        <div></div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply in xml file update this model="ir.actions.act_window" with view_mode like:

```
      <record id="action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Name1</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">model_name</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,calendar,graph,gantt</field>
.....
</record>
```

This is the way how to call all view, and link http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/openerp-61-framework-changes will help u how to create kanban view.
I hope it will help you...